# SymmetricDS alter table foreign key references issue

Tags: azure-sql-database, open-source, symmetricds

While running SymmetricDS for database syncrhonization for Azure SQL Database for two Azure SQL databases namely, Staging_Prod & DBSYNC_STAGING_PROD, I am facing the following error.

```
2018-10-22 06:50:46,706 WARN [secondary-staging_prod-us-001] [JdbcSqlTemplate] [secondary-staging_prod-us-001-dataloader-6] Foreign key 'FK_AccessMaster_ToFunctions' references invalid table 'STAGING_PROD.Functions'..  Failed to execute: ALTER TABLE "dbo"."AccessMaster"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_AccessMaster_ToFunctions" FOREIGN KEY ("FunctionID") REFERENCES "STAGING_PROD"."Functions" ("id")
2018-10-22 06:50:46,706 ERROR [secondary-staging_prod-us-001] [DefaultDatabaseWriter] [secondary-staging_prod-us-001-dataloader-6] Failed to alter table using the following xml: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE database SYSTEM "http://db.apache.org/torque/dtd/database">
<database name="dataextractor" schema="dbo">
    <table name="AccessMaster">
        <column name="Id" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER" size="10" autoIncrement="true">
            <platform-column name="mssql2008" type="int identity" size="10"/>
        </column>
        <column name="HTML_UI_ID" required="true" type="VARCHAR" size="50">
            <platform-column name="mssql2008" type="varchar" size="50"/>
        </column>
        <column name="Name" required="true" type="VARCHAR" size="50">
            <platform-column name="mssql2008" type="varchar" size="50"/>
        </column>
        <column name="Value" required="true" type="BIGINT" size="19">
            <platform-column name="mssql2008" type="bigint" size="19"/>
        </column>
        <column name="FunctionID" required="true" type="INTEGER" size="10">
            <platform-column name="mssql2008" type="int" size="10"/>
        </column>
        <foreign-key name="FK_AccessMaster_ToFunctions" foreignTable="Functions" foreignTableCatalog="STAGING_PROD" foreignTableSchema="">
            <reference local="FunctionID" foreign="ID"/>
        </foreign-key>
        <unique name="AK_AccessMaster_HTML_UI_ID_FunctionID">
            <unique-column name="HTML_UI_ID"/>
            <unique-column name="FunctionID"/>
        </unique>
    </table>
</database> StackTraceKey [SqlException:1229404539]
2018-10-22 06:50:46,752 ERROR [secondary-staging_prod-us-001] [ManageIncomingBatchListener] [secondary-staging_prod-us-001-dataloader-6] Failed to load batch 000-11 StackTraceKey [SqlException:1229404539]
```

The SymmetricDS config tables are as follows.

```
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('primary-staging_prod-us');
insert into sym_node_group (node_group_id) values ('secondary-staging_prod-us');

insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', 'W');
insert into sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action) values ('secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', 'P');


insert into sym_trigger 
(trigger_id,source_catalog_name,source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_insert, sync_on_update, sync_on_delete, last_update_time,create_time, sync_on_incoming_batch)
values('TriggerAll', null, 'dbo', '*', 'matter', 1 , 1, 1, GetDate(), GetDate(), 1);


insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', null, 'dbo', '*', 'default',GetDate(), GetDate());

insert into sym_router 
(router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,router_type,create_time,last_update_time)
values('secondary_2_primary-staging_prod-us', 'secondary-staging_prod-us', 'primary-staging_prod-us', null, 'dbo', '*', 'default', GetDate(), GetDate());


insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll','primary_2_secondary-staging_prod-us', 100, current_timestamp,current_timestamp);
insert into sym_trigger_router (trigger_id,router_id,initial_load_order,last_update_time,create_time)
values('TriggerAll','secondary_2_primary-staging_prod-us', 200, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

But if I execute the alter command in the SQL Server Management Studio as below with the correct target schema it runs fine.

```
ALTER TABLE "dbo"."AccessMaster"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_AccessMaster_ToFunctions" FOREIGN KEY ("FunctionID") REFERENCES "DBSYNC_STAGING_PROD"."dbo"."Functions" ("id")
```

SymmetricDS version ==> symmetric-server-3.9.14

I think the issue is coming as I am not able to specify target schema/catalog name. Could you please guide me through the configuration step in the new symmetricDS version.

Regards
Rajat Agrawal

Comment: `sym_router. target_catalog_name` is set to `null`. have you tried setting it to the actual catalog name of the target db for the related router?

Comment: I modified the target_catalog_name column in sym_router table but it has started giving the below error.   2018-10-22 09:51:31,804 ERROR [secondary-staging_prod-us-001] [RegistrationService] [secondary-staging_prod-us-001-job-2] Unexpected error during registration: Failed to retrieve tables for trigger with id of TriggerAll StackTraceKey.init 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to retrieve tables for trigger with id of TriggerAll  Caused by: org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.

Comment: For these kind of corner cases I would recommend checking out the source code of symmetricds, enable remote debugging, connect with your IDE and remote debug

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved. Looks like there is a BUG in SymmetricDS version 3.9.14 released on 3rd Oct. 2018. I just downloaded the stable version 3.8.40 released on 9th August 2018 and the error is gone and I am able to sync schema changes without any foreign key references error.

Regards

Rajat Agrawal